# Ubuntu 20.04.1 : Bluetooth Headset connection problems

Tags: 20.04, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I connect bluetooth headset via bluetooth menu.

1. I can't switch to A2DP Sink profile.
2. If I power off the computer and start again and let the bluetooth headset connect automatically it is not recognized as an audio device.
3. If I connect the headset manually by turning on the following button, in bluetooth settings, my headset is being recognized as an audio device but I still can't switch to A2DP Sink.
   [image]
4. If by following some suggestion I edit the /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf and geth the A2DP Sink working I can't switch back to HSP/HPF ( [Link to Article about fixing A2DP](https://medium.com/@overcode/fixing-bluetooth-in-ubuntu-pop-os-18-04-d4b8dbf7ddd6) )
5. My headset was working fine for some time flawlessly switching between both profiles in all the cases, I don't know what changed.

Comment: Problem occurred after a recent update to the Ubuntu software?

Comment: @David seems so.